# Attachment of .msg file from excel using python and attach to another excel file

Tags: python, excel, attachment

I have an excel sheet that has a .msg added as an attachment(embedded) into it. I want to download the attachment using python and then attach the same downloaded file into another excel file.

https://pypi.org/project/AttachmentsExtractor/

suggests the following

`from AttachmentsExtractor import extractor`

list of file extensions supported

.xlsx
.xlsm
.xltx
.xltm
.docx
.dotx
.docm
.dotm
.pptx
.pptm
.potx
.potm

But my attachment has extension as .msg

Any help would be appreciated!